# ASP .Net MVC Web Application Search Filter does not work?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am working on an ASP .Net Core Web Application using Entity Framework Core.

I have a table and want to filter according to columns. Now I just start with filtering with userName, then I will expand the code for other columns.

First of all, I have a Filter Model.

```
public class HistoryFilterModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
   // public string UserSays { get; set; }
   // public DateTime CreateDateFrom { get; set; }
   // public DateTime CreateDateTo { get; set; }
}
```

And I have FilterService

```
public class HistoryFiltersService
{
    private MainContext _context;

 
    public HistoryFiltersService(MainContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IQueryable<History> GetHistories(HistoryFilterModel filterModel)
    {
        var result = _context.History.AsQueryable();
        if( filterModel != null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterModel.UserName))
                result = result.Where(x => x.UserName.Contains(filterModel.UserName)); 

            //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterModel.UserSays))
            //    result = result.Where(x => x.UserSays.Contains(filterModel.UserSays)); 

            //if (filterModel.CreateDateFrom.Date != null)
            //    result = result.Where(x => x.CreateDate.Date >= filterModel.CreateDateFrom); 

            //if (filterModel.CreateDateTo.Date != null)
            //    result = result.Where(x => x.CreateDate.Date <= filterModel.CreateDateTo); 
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

After that, I work on the Index method of HistoryController.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(HistoryFilterModel filterModel, int page = 1 )
    {
        var pageSize = 50;
        var history = _context.History
          .OrderByDescending(m => m.CreateDate);

        var pagingHistory = history.Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);


        var totalCount = history.Count();
        var totalPages = Math.Ceiling((decimal)totalCount / pageSize);
        ViewBag.TotalPages = totalPages;

        var filter = new HistoryFiltersService(_context);
        var model = filter.GetHistories(filterModel);

       

        if (! string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterModel.UserName))
        {
            return View(model.ToListAsync());
            
        }
        else
        {
            return View(await history.ToListAsync());
        }

    }
```

And I add a search textbox on the Index view

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "HistoryController", FormMethod.Get))
            {
            <p>
                User Name: @Html.TextBox("filterModel.UserName")
                <input type="submit" value="Filtrele" class="btn btn-primary" />

            </p>
            }
```

When I search a user name for example Alex. (There is an data in History table)
I got an error :

**No web page was found for the following web address http://localhost:XXXX/HistoryController?filterModel.UserName=Alex**

How can I fix this? Or could you suggest any approach to filter table data like working like in excel sheet column filtering?

Comment: You shouldn't refere to the controller with the text "HistoryController" but just with the text "History"

Comment: Where are you getting that error?

Comment: Also,  _@Html.TextBox("filterModel.UserName")_ should be _@Html.TextBoxFor(model =>model.UserName)_

Comment: Hi @Steve I fix the text "HistoryController" where you mentioned in the first comment. The run time error is fixed. Then I applied your second comment (I tried this before I asked the question.) There is an error that is  **'IEnumerable<History>' does not contain a definition for 'UserName'** . But History contains a definition for UserName, and also below this code block, there is another code block for table. I use that one    **@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)** and there is no error for the UserName. I confused little bit.

Comment: _@Html.TextBox("UserName", "", new { @class = "form-control" })_ but I really suggest you to separate the model used for the search from the model used to display the table data. Also it is a good practice to use a ViewModel for the data to be displayed and not directly the model used to interact with your database context